# jquery loading site one by one from json array

Tags: jquery, json, function

I am trying to loading sites from a JSON array to divs one by one. (once loading has finished, then loading the next one), but I do not know how to set it by myself? Sorry for jsfiddle.net
not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//var mark = false;
//if(mark==false){
    //var json = {"set":"[{'web':'google','site':'http://www.google.com'},{'web':'bing','site':'http://www.bing.com'},{'web':'yahoo','site':'http://www.yahoo.com'}]"} 
    var json = {"set":"[{'web':'google','site':'1.html'},{'web':'bing','site':'2.html'},{'web':'yahoo','site':'3.html'}]"} 

    json = eval(json.set);
    for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
        var divid = json[i].web;
        var url = json[i].site;
        $('#'+divid+'').load(''+url+'',function(){
            //mark = false;
        });
    }
//}
});



<div id="google"></div>

<div id="bing"></div>

<div id="yahoo"></div>​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sorry for jsfiddle.net not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Your problem has nothing to do with jsfiddle. Due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions that's built in browsers you simply cannot send AJAX requests cross domain. You can forget about doing:

```
$('#google').load('http://www.google.com');
```

unless of course the page containing this script is hosted on `http://www.google.com`.

In your case you could build a server side script on your domain (using some server side language such as PHP, Java Servlets, ASP.NET, ...) that will serve as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain that you are trying to fetch. Then you will send your AJAX request to your server side script.

You may also take a look at the [following article](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) which explains some cross domain AJAX techniques.

---

UPDATE:

Assuming you want to queue your AJAX requests in such a way that the second request is triggered only after the first succeeds and so on you could write a recursive method:

```
$(function() {
    // TODO: it's pretty trivial to build this list array given your initial
    // json object, so I am not including it here
    var list = [
        { url: '/url1/', target: '#google' },
        { url: '/url2/', target: '#bing' },
        { url: '/url3/', target: '#yahoo' },
    ];

    (function(list) {
        var element = list.shift();
        if (element) {
            var caller = arguments.callee.caller;
            $(element.target).load(element.url, function() {
                caller(list);
            });
        }
    })(list);
});
```

Comment: hi, i am not care about `jsfiddle.net`, (just a test platform) I just want to know how to control loading one by one? thanks.

Comment: @yulichika, since you are trigerring your AJAX requests in parallel you have no control over how long they will take. Do you want them to appear *sequential* (trigger the second request only after the first has finished and so on)?

Comment: yes. i want when the first request finished then trigger the second request. in the fact, i will loading my page. google,bing,yahoo just for a question that easy for test. thanks.

Comment: @yulichika, OK, please see my update for an example on how to achieve that.